# Angular error handling in submit function just hangs

Tags: angular

I would like my error handling to not just hang when a form is submitted, rather it should display an error in a div in Angular, so far my submit function looks like this:

```
onSubmit() {
    if(this.serviceForm.invalid) {
       this.serviceForm.setErrors({ ...this.serviceForm.errors, 'required': true });
       return;
    }
    //this.loading = true;
    this.uploading = true;
    this.service.postRequest(this.serviceForm.value).subscribe((response: any) => {
      console.log(response);//On success response
      this.router.navigate(['/confirmation'],{queryParams: {value: response.result[0].display_value}});
    }, (errorResponse: any) => {
      console.log(errorResponse); //On unsuccessful response
    });
    }
  }
```

Comment: i created a class export class ValidationItem {
    property: string;
    error: string;} and then i filled a collection of validation item and after that in my component i showed them with an ngfor. tell me if it works for you so i will do some implimentation for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have :

```
error:string = "";

...

onSubmit() {
   ...
  (errorResponse: any) => {
      this.error = "Your custom error message, could be conditional on your type of error";
  }
}
```

And in your html:

```
<div *ngIf="error"> 
   {{ error }}
</div>
```